# Sending and getting data from basic HTML

Tags: html

Is there any way to send data from one HTML page to another using **basic** HTML without using JavaScript and PHP?

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to "**send**" data:

```
<a href="my_other_page?data1=1234567">Send</a>
```

but there is no way for the receiving page to **parse** it without a server-side application or JavaScript. (Or Flash, or a Java applet, or an ActiveX control....)

Answer (score 2):

**html** only purpose is to show content. It is not designed for getting and passing data. you need server side script to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Good answers.  Pekka and Andre really nailed it.

**In order to pass data from HTML form fields to your web application:**

1) You can manually build a link with query string variables *(basically Pekka's example)*

```
<a href="signup.pl?name=john">Submit</a>
```

2) Or, to retrieve data typed in by the user (which is typically what you want), you can use the [`GET` method](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_METHOD_GET.html)

```
<form action="signup.pl" method="get">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Either way, you end up with a post to the web server with the same URL *(provided the user typed "john")*:

> http://www.mycatwebsite.com/signup.pl?name=john

(or you can use `POST` instead of `GET`, but then query string variables don't show up in the URL)

**But in order to read and process it, as already mentioned, you need a server side programming language.**

Even the first dynamic websites back in the 90's used CGI Perl scripts, or even ANSI C, to process data.  Here's a simple Perl example:

- [HTML Forms POST, GET](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/html/html-forms-post-get-050821-1041/)

Now of course there are many web application languages (and frameworks) to choose from, such as PHP, Java, ASP.NET, Ruby, Python, etc.  But they all adhere to the CGI convention of passing data back and forth (CGI Request/HTML response) between the web server (Apache, IIS) and the web site.

- [Common Gateway Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)
- [Dynamic website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website#Dynamic_website)

Answer (score 1):

You can prompt the user to enter data with a `<form>`, and you can add GET-query-parameters to your URL (`index.php?foo=bar`). But to work with the received data, you will need to use a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can send data but can't process sent data. For it you must use PHP, javascript or something similar...